# attempting to read values and putting them from greatest to least

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, file-io

I have a file that has the following values:
2
4
8
10

Im attempting to sort them out from greatest to least, but im having issues as it is not functioning properly, giving me a list like 8,2,4.
here is my code:

```
public void highScore ()
{
    int highScore = 0;
    String line = "";
    int x = 0;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("highScores.txt"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)                 // read the score file line by line
        {
            x++;

        }
        reader.close ();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println ("ERROR reading scores from file");
    }
    int[] y = new int [x];
    int b = 0;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("highScores.txt"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)                 // read the score file line by line
        {
            int d = Integer.parseInt (line);
            y [b] = d;
            b++;
        }
        reader.close ();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println ("ERROR reading scores from file");
    }
    int tempVar;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < y.length - 1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < y.length - 1 ; j++)
        {
            if (y [i] < y [j])
            {
                tempVar = y [j + 1];
                y [j + 1] = y [i];
                y [i] = tempVar;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < y.length - 1 ; i++)
    {
        c.println (y [i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your bubble sort implementation is slightly off. Here is the fixed version:

```
    int k;
    int tempVar;
    for (int i = y.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length - 1; j++) {
            k = j + 1;
            if (y[j] < y[k]) {
                tempVar = y[j];
                y[j] = y[k];
                y[k] = tempVar;
            }
        }
    }
// and printing doesn't need length - 1
   for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {...}
```

Also you can accomplish the same using higher level functionality of java. Here is a much simpler version using java 8 streams and lambdas:

```
try {
    Stream<String> lineStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("highScores.txt"));
    List<Integer> result = lineStream
            .map(line -> line.trim()) //remove whitespace
            .map(line -> Integer.valueOf(line)) //parse string to integer
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o2, o1)) // reverse sort
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect results into list
    result.forEach(score -> System.out.println(score));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this in your code

```
Integer[] y = {2,4,6,8};
        Arrays.sort(y,new Comparator<Integer>(){

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(arg0 == arg1)
                return 0;
                else if(arg0 < arg1)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return -1;
            }

        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
```